# Is it possible to select multiple equal elements in capybara?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'm starting to study automated testing with the following gems `capybara`,`cucumber`,`SitePrism`,`webdriver`, one thing I see a lot happening in my tests is Input type fields if they repeat.

Some like that:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="some cool text"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="some cool text"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="some cool text"/>
```

So I'm wondering, if it is possible to define some value in all fields at the same time, something like:

```
site.find('[placeholder="some cool text"]').set('A simple string')
```

I'm having trouble finding an answer to that, there would be no problem making loops to define one at a time, but I have no idea how to select them at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is limited to returning one element, if you want multiple you'll want to use `all`.  Using Capybara something like

```
page.all('input', text: 'some cool text').each do |inp| 
  inp.set('A simple string')
end
```

would do what you're asking.  If you wanted to make sure it was exactly 3 matching elements that were handled you would use the `count` option (there are`also`minimum`,` maximum`, and` between` options available)

```
page.all('input', text: 'some cool text', count: 3).each do |inp| 
  inp.set('A simple string')
end
```

Update: Since you've updated the question you could do

```
page.all("input[placeholder='some cool text']", count: 3).each do |inp| 
  inp.set('A simple string')
end
```

but I would probably use the Capybara provided selector types like

```
page.all(:fillable_field, placeholder: 'some cool text', count: 3).each do |inp|
  inp.set('A simple string')
end
```

Comment: You helped me a lot, I didn't know this concept, however to evaluate how correct it is necessary to edit the answer, due to an accident of mine, where it is usually `('input', text: 'some cool text')`, it is to receive `("[placeholder='some cool text']")`, I will edit my question too.

Comment: @WEBLastWolf Added updated info to the answer based on your changes to the question